# Conditional styling in v-for vuejs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

i have made a calendar in momentjs and would like to color e.g the weekends differently.

The dates and days are rendered in a v-for like so:

```
<tr v-for="(day, index) in days" :key="index" class="grid-container">
    <td class="grid-item">{{ day.date.format("Do") }}</td>
    <td class="grid-item">{{ day.date.format("dddd") }}</td>
    <td class="grid-item">{{ day.workhours }}</td>
    <td class="grid-item">{{ day.overtime }}</td>
    <td class="grid-item">{{ day.flextime}}</td>
    <td class="grid-item">{{ day.sickness}}</td>
    <td class="grid-item">{{ day.vacation}}</td>
   </tr>
```

is it possible to change e.g the background color of all of these td's  if

```
day.date == "Saturday"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [class binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

**update:**
I missed the name of the day, I added what [Jose Fernández](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63904218/3149249) suggested

template:

```
<tr
  v-for="(day, index) in days"
  :key="index"
  v-bind:class="{ active: day.format('dddd') == 'Saturday' }"
  class="grid-container"
>
  ...
</tr>
```

style:

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
.active {
  background-color: green;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I would have thought so too, but when i add that and look in the developer tools, the class is not added to the <tr> elements that contains Saturday. Can it have something to do with the day.date not having been formatted yet?

Comment: ty it works now, just needed to reset my eyes and implement your solution accordingly

Answer (score 1):

I think what [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63902697/7513945) replied is the finest solution. Although I think what you want to check is:

```
day.date.format("dddd") == 'Saturday'
```